# Gradle warning: "The libsDir method has been deprecated."

Tags: gradle

I'm using Gradle 5.6.1 with a `build.gradle` file that publishes a distribution to Artifactory.

When I run the publish task, I receive a warning:

```
$ gradle publishMyPublicationToRemoteArtifactoryRepository
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
```

Using the suggested flag reveals `The libsDir method has been deprecated.`:

```
$ gradle publishMyPublicationToRemoteArtifactoryRepository --warning-mode all
> Configure project :
The libsDir method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0.
```

The relevant section of `build.gradle` is below:

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = archivesBaseName

        contents {
            from libsDir
        }
    }
}
```

How do I correct `libsDir` so that the warning is resolved?

Answer (score 4):

Referencing the `libsDir` directly usually indicates bad design and often can be avoided with a different approach to the problem.

However, for those who are looking for a direct replacement and are using Gradle 6.0 or higher, it is `libsDirectory`.

The default value with java plugin is `${project.buildDir}/${project.libsDirName}`, you may also use it as a replacement if that's what you want.

Please see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePluginConvention.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePluginConvention:libsDir

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion [on GitHub](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9470) where the following alternative is suggested:

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = archivesBaseName

        contents {
            from "${buildDir}/${distsDirName}"
        }
    }
}
```